# Problem at login following update to Ubuntu Studio 22.04

Tags: updates, 22.04, themes, lenovo, login-screen

I have a Lenovo T460p  Laptop with Core i5 CPU, 16GB RAM and a 250GB SSD.

Error message at login page:

```
The current theme cannot be loaded due to the errors below please select another theme.
```

See picture joint at this message:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem this morning (running Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1). Yesterday, I updated a few packages including ubuntustudio-default-settings and I suspect that's where the problem came from.

I found a workaround. In the system settings, under Workspace > Startup and Shutdown > Login Screen (SDDM), I have a choice of three themes: Breeze, and two apparently identical Ubuntu Studio themes. Not sure if the duplicate theme appeared today: it may have been there previously. I selected the Breeze theme, clicked Apply, then restarted the computer. Login works normally now and the theme is fairly similar to what I was using before.

If you want to try it and don't see the Breeze theme, I think you can get it by installing the package sddm-theme-breeze.

Could the ubuntustudio-default-settings update have introduced a bug in the Ubuntu Studio SDDM theme? Hard to tell. I should mention I already had a problem with SDDM: every once in a while, the login screen would freeze. Never found a solution for that, only a workaround: open a virtual terminal (using Ctrl-Alt-F3, for instance), login, then use "sudo service sddm restart".

Comment: Thank you for your post ! 

My login works normaly now,

Answer (score 0):

Update the `ubuntustudio-default-settings` package (if you have not done so already). This was due to a problem that has now been resolved in the latest release: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plasma-workspace/+bug/2003388